# sed command in bash script to change YAML file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a YAML file like below:

```
server:
  scheme: http
  host: localhost
  port: 8080
  context: myctx

report:
  output-dir-base: /tmp
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
vertica:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:vertica://server:65534/database
    username: user
    password: db_pass

da-config:
  user: username
  password: da_pass
  da-host:
    scheme: http
    server: server
    port: 65535
```

From a bash script I want to replace Vertica password with a given value, let's say "first_pass" and da password with "second_pass".

I tried this but didn't work.

```
sed '/^vertica:\([[:space:]]*password: \).*/s//\1first_pass/' common-properties.yaml
```

Can this be helped with, please?

## UPDATE:

This is what I did to handle the situation. In the bash script file

```
DB_PASSWORD="first_pass/here" ## I realized later that the password could contain a '/' char as well
DA_PASSWORD="second_pass"

sed -i '/vertica:/{n;n;n;n;s/\(password\).*/\1: '"${DB_PASSWORD//\//\\/}"'/}' my.yaml  ## backslash-escape the '/' in the variable

sed -i '/da-config:/{n;n;s/\(password\).*/\1: '"${DA_PASSWORD//\//\\/}"'/}' my.yaml
```

Comment: Much safer to use a syntax-aware tool rather than something like sed that doesn't actually understand the YAML format.

Comment: I have to use this script in a customer env and customer doesn't allow installing additional tools. So I am stuck with standard bash tools!

Comment: ...the _easiest_ way to do this is to restructure your "YAML" file to be JSON (all JSON is also valid YAML), and then you can use widespread tools like `jq`. There _are_ other YAML-specific tools -- two separate ones under the `yq` name, mutually incompatible with each other, f/e -- but they're not as widespread.

Comment: Re: "standard bash tools" -- your customer doesn't have Python? (Python has a proper JSON parser built-in; change your input to be JSON and there you are). I haven't heard of a major OS that doesn't ship with Python out-of-the-box in a lot of years now.

Comment: I checked that already. I am comfortable with ```jq```, ```yq```, ```Python``` but not possible in given env.

Comment: This worked for me: ```sed "/vertica:/{n;n;n;n;s/\(password\).*/\1: first_pass/}" my.yaml``` I will use this command twice with ```-i``` option

Comment: Does this work?   sed -i '/vertica/{n;N;N;N;s/\(password: \).*/\1first_pass/};/da-config/{n;N;s/\(password: \).*/\1second_pass/}'

Comment: @HatLess the command you provided only replaces the first password. Second password is not replaced. Moreover, when I run my command, they work well on command line. But when placed in shell script, it gives as error ```sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unknown option to `s'``` To overcome the error, I replace ```"``` with ```'``` , that works but doesn't expand the env variables e.g if I want to use $FIRST_PASS instead of first_pass

Comment: please update the question with the (wrong) output generated by your script and the (correct) expected output;

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- input is nicely formatted as displayed in question
- OP does not have access to tools designed specifically for yaml editing

New passwords stored in variables:

```
pass1='first_pass'
pass2='second_pass'
```

One `sed` idea using ranges to zero in on the sections we're interested in:

```
sed -E "/^vertica:/,/password:/ s/(password:).*/\1 ${pass1}/; /^da-config:/,/password:/ s/(password:).*/\1 ${pass2}/; " common-properties.yaml

# or, as OP has mentioned in an update, when the password contains a forward slash we change the sed script delimiter:

sed -E "/^vertica:/,/password:/ s|(password:).*|\1 ${pass1}|; /^da-config:/,/password:/ s|(password:).*|\1 ${pass2}|; " common-properties.yaml
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v p1="${pass1}" -v p2="${pass2}" '

$1 == "password:" { if ( found1 ) { sub(/password: .*/,"password: " p1); found1=0 }
                    if ( found2 ) { sub(/password: .*/,"password: " p2); found2=0 }
                  }
/^vertica:/       { found1=1 }
/^da-config:/     { found2=1 }
1
' common-properties.yaml
```

Both of these generate:

```
server:
  scheme: http
  host: localhost
  port: 8080
  context: myctx

report:
  output-dir-base: /tmp
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
vertica:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:vertica://server:65534/database
    username: user
    password: first_pass

da-config:
  user: username
  password: second_pass
  da-host:
    scheme: http
    server: server
    port: 65535
```

Once OP is satisified with the output:

- for `sed` add the `-i` option to update-in-place the file
- if using `GNU awk` add `-i inplace` to update-in-place the file; if not running `GNU awk` then save the output to a temp file and then overwrite the input file with the contents of the temp file